# Popover visibility issue in the stacks editor

Tags: bug, design, tooltips, stacks-editor

In the Stacks editor, the popover on top becomes invisible when hovering over the tools icon, significantly when the editor menu block extends to the end of the page.

**Screenshot for reference:**
[image: Hover over - Image]

Popover behavior changes before and after the menu reaches the end of the page:

> [image: Hover over - GIF]

| Configuration | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 11 Pro |
| Mozilla Firefox | 117.0.1 (64-bit) |
| Google Chrome | 117.0.5938.89 (Official Build) (64-bit) |
| Zoom | 100% |

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Win 10, latest Firefox (117.0.1) x64.

Comment: @Mast I have updated the configuration

Comment: I'm able to duplicate this on SO and in Teams using Firefox on Win 10.